# Make image perspective for different views in php

Tags: php, perspective

I'm asking you if you know a good method to make perspective on image in php.

I've got some render images that rotate and I want let the user the possibility to upload an image 
and view this image on the different views of the render with a correct perspective.

I'm using Imagick and I've tried to do that with DISTORTION_PERSPECTIVE but the result lacks of quality.

Regards,
D.

Comment: Can you clarify please? As I currently understand the question it basically violates all of the most fundamental laws of physic in this universe.

Comment: "*..but the result lacks of quality..*" Ok. So What "Quality" You Are Looking For?

Comment: I'm making a shoe configurator.
I can change the various colors of the parts and I can rotate the shoe because I've got an array of images of the shoe.
When I do the change a color, I make an Ajx request and I return an array with the new images. I create the new combinations combining different images with php imagick.Now I want let the user to upload a logo and attach it on the shoe.
When I return the images array from the server, I want see this logo attached on the images in perspective respect of the angle of the image.
My question is: what is the best way to do that?